# AWS Cognito : Sign in with either email or phone number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have set up cognito user pool where both email and phone number is configured for sign in.

[image]

below is the code for signup,

```
const handleSignup = async () => {

const email = 'meXXX1@XXXXX.com';
const password = 'Saurabh@123';

const params = {
  ClientId: '71otcXXXXXXXXXXXXeaXXs',
  Username: email,
  Password: password,
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: 'meXXX1@XXXXX.com'
    },
    {
      Name: 'phone_number',
      Value: '+918XXX65143'
    }
  ]
};

try {
  const data = await cognitoClient.signUp(params).promise();
  console.log(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

};

However when i try to login with phone number getting error
{__type: "NotAuthorizedException", message: "Incorrect username or password."}
message
:
"Incorrect username or password."
__type
:
"NotAuthorizedException"

the login through email works fine.
Here is the code to login through mobile number:

```
 const mobileSignIn = async () =>{

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });
const params = {
  AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
  ClientId: '71otXXXXXXXXXauXXXXXXs',
  AuthParameters: {
    USERNAME: '+918XXXXXXX3',
    PASSWORD: 'Saurabh@123',
  },
};
try {
  const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.initiateAuth(params).promise();
  console.log('Successfully signed in!', data.AuthenticationResult);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error signing in:', error);
}
```

}

How can I signin using mobile number?